# Is there a way to change number words to numeric numbers between other text in a string in python?

Tags: speech-to-text

i have implemented vosk library to recognise speech in python, now i am able to recognise speech .

But , I want to detect digits as numeric currently library returning word of numeric speech.Like if speech is "1 2 3 4 and this 1005 post" so Result will be : one two three four and this one thousand five post

Out put should be : 1 2 3 4 and the 1005 post

Can anyone please assist...?

This is what I get when I ask him the question?

sir: one two three four and this one thousand and five post
AlfredQueryOfflineInt: one two three four and this one thousand and five post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.